# React (get loop or no results) when call function from map to return total inventory

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 databases **products** + **productItems**

In a list of the products, I'm trying to display a column with total inventory

- total_inventory = sum of product's items inventory

I tried to call a function that check and return the `total_inventory` to display for each product

How can I get the value to display?   (I got the totals to print, but not to display)

1. Tried to use `axios`  and  `fetch` - couldn't return the value from within fetch/axios, or set it to state (because it'll create a loop)
2. If for instance I could print the line of console.log(total) - how can I get it out of their to return from the function?

Thank you!

Code below (map & function):

```
{state.products.map((productDetails, index) => {
                return  (
                           <div>
                             <row>
                                 <col style={{margin: 'auto'}}>
                                      {productTotalInventory(productDetails.id)}
                                 </col>
                            </row>
                               </div>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const productTotalInventory = (productId) => {
        async function fetchObjectDetails(productId) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subProducts/?product_id=', productId)
                const json = await response.json()
                const total = json.reduce((totalInventory, item) => totalInventory + item.inventory_total, 0)
                console.log(total)
                return total
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        return fetchObjectDetails(productId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite clear on what you are asking, but I noticed that you might be making the fetch call incorrectly. To access data that is passed into your function you need to use the template literals. So maybe try replacing

('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subProducts/?product_id=', productId)

with

```
(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subProducts/?product_id= ${productId}`)
```

Comment: If for instance I could print the line of `console.log(total)` - how can I get it out of their to return from the function?

Comment: Add const [ total, setTotal] = useState('') at the top and replace console.log(total) in the function with setTotal(total)

Comment: If I update state it'll render again, and will create a loop